# Mongodb query that combines $and and $exists

Tags: mongodb

My collection has the following structure:

```
- file_path (string)
- file_contents(object)
    - a[] (array)
    - b[] (array)
```

An example document could be like:

- file_path : "/username/innerdirectory/file.txt"
- file_contents:

  - a: [0,1,1,1,0]
  - b: [0,0,0,1,1]

I am trying to find out all the documents that have a particular `file_path` and that have `file_contents.a` in them.

My query at the moment looks like this:

```
db.logs.find({$and:[{'file_path':"/username/innerdirectory/file.txt"},{file_contents.a:{$exists: true}}]})
```

It says `SyntaxError: missing : after property id`

Is my query even right?

Comment: Try putting quotes on "file_contents.a"

Comment: Tried that, doesn't give an error, but gives no result either. Although for my particular file name, the field `file_contents.a` does in fact exist

Comment: Then you should try in an example where some result must be returned... I mean, where `file_contents.a` exists

Comment: That's what I tried, it does exist for the document for which I tried it

Comment: FYI. You almost never need `$and` as [ALL MongoDB query operations are already AND conditions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/#specify-and-conditions) "by default". `{ "file_path": "/username/innerdirectory/file.txt", "file_contents.a": { "$exists": true } }`

Comment: @NeilLunn But with $and it should work, right?

Comment: @Héctor Yes, however it's really superfluous and overly terse. The whole point on any operator in the DSL which uses an `Array` as an argument is to "avoid key name collision". 9/10 times even multiple conditions simply assign to the same key. i.e `{ "value": { "$gt": 1, "$lt": 3 } }` is actually an AND expression on the same key. Not the point anyway. The issue is with the "dot notation" being required to be quoted.